# Repeat the same ag-grid (7.2.2)

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid in my html, and I want to put a button so that when I press that same ag-grid is shown but in a modal to be able to see it in more detail, but it is in the same html, and the ag-grid is exactly the same.

It can be done so that the same ag-grid is seen in the same html and controller.

Since he does not paint me anything but one.

HTML:

```
<div ag-grid="agGridBusqueda" class="ag-enel h113"></div>
```

.....

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div ag-grid="agGridBusqueda" class="ag-enel h113"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to display two grid instances at the same time? The non-modal one should still be visible in the background?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to render the same grid two times, in a modal and in a background. You would need to make a separate grid and update the values manually.

I also think this would be both terrible for the performance and the usability. The user would see grid-lines in the background when opening a modal (from the original grid) which would change as he modifies the modal-grid; I think this is disturbing. And you would have 2x the amount of rendered rows and input listeners on your screen.

I think the cleaner solution would be to just use one instance of ag-grid and (on button-click) assign `class="modal-body"` to it, making the container element float with an extended width and dimmed background.